# Writing a DelayedJob custom job to run script and then destroy object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, background-process

I've been trying to figure this out for a long time, and can't figure it out.

I am using DelayedJob in my Rails app in order to run a script to fill out some forms on a website via a Mechanize script. However, after the job completes, I don't want any record of the entry to be stored in any database in my application, as there is no reason anyone should access it again.

The process works perfectly when I ran it as a simple background method within the controller's `create` method - that is, by calling `@course.delay.scrape` right after `if @course.save`. But now that I want to destroy the object right after the background job finishes, I believe I need to create a custom job, and am struggling with that.

I am aware that the DelayedJob documentation lists the method `def after(job)`. In order to use that method, I need to create a custom job. I'm confused about how to create a custom job, as nearly every example I can find is for sending mass emails, whereas this is for a different purpose. I don't know how to get the script to run this way.

If you can help me with fixing up this code at all, that would be greatly appreciated! I've tried many variations, looking at as many examples as possible. I'm aware it has at least a few errors, but am not advanced enough to know what to change. This is the last thing I tried before throwing in the towel.

Here is my model (in models/course.rb):

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

 after_create :send_to_delayed_job

 def scrape
   ...Mechanize script goes here ....
 end

 def send_to_delayed_job
  Delayed::Job.enqueue CourseJob.new(self.id), :queue => 'mycoursequeue'
 end
end
```

Here is my job (in models/course_job.rb):

```
class CourseJob < Struct.new(:course_id)

 def perform
  course = Course.find(self.id)
  course.scrape
 end

 def after(job)
  Course.destroy(params[:id])
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Can we just have `course.destroy` as the last line of `CourseJob#perform` method?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I went ahead and clarified my question above. That's a really good idea, but unfortunately, I can't get the process to work at all through a custom job (although it worked through the regular delay method previously). Until I can figure that out, I can't get the record to consequently destroy.

Comment: May I know how you tested that it's not working with the custom Job object? Because from my opinion, your issue is very strange ...